# Develope ArcGIS Desktop Add-Ins with ArcGIS Runtime SDK

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, add-in, arcgis-runtime, sdk

I need to learn develop add-in in ArcGIS 10.3. I have this book :

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-ArcGIS-Desktop-Development-using/dp/1118442547](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118442547)

but he was using visual studio 2010 and ArcGIS Runtime SDK 10.1.
I have Visual Studio 2013 and ArcGIS Runtime SDK 10.2.5

He used ArcGIS Add-Ins Wizard. but i can't find Add-Ins Wizard in visual studio 2013. How can i develop Add-In in SDK 10.2.5 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS Runtime SDK and ArcGIS Addins are two different things. If you want to develop standalone application then choose ArcGIS Runtime Sdk. If you want to extend ArcGIS Desktop , then you should start developing with ArcObjects (e.g. using addins). So first install ArcGIS Desktop and then install ArcObject SDK for .NET which is accompanied with ArcGIS Desktop installation media.

Comment: thank you for answer my friend, I found ArcObject SDK. I'll try it now...

Comment: I would add that although Runtime and AddIns are different the objects are the same - you use the same help document so the book should be almost as valid for addins as for runtime. The differences in visual studio versions shouldn't matter too much, use the version that's supported by your ArcGis version.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Menubar go to

*File->New->Project*.

Then a dialog opens, there you can choose in

*Templates/ Visual C#/ ArcGIS/ Desktop Add-ins*

and in example ArcMap-AddIn. Give your new Project a nice Name and click OK and then the ArcGIS Add-Ins Wizard should open.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I thought ArcGIS Runtime SDK and ArcObject SDK is same think but, it was wrond. I have learned from Farid Cher.